Overriding load_and_authorize_resource of super class
I am trying to use cancancan gem in rails. I have a controller named CPController inside which I have declared load_and_authorize_resource. Another controller ParticipantsController inherits from this controller. Inside the ParticipantsController I want to override this specific functionality such as load_and_authorize_resource class: 'User', instance_name: 'user' since the name of my model is user. Is there any way I can do it?
I have tried simply adding this line in ParticipantsController but it gives me an NameError (uninitialized constant Participant). My guess it it still runs the load_and_authorize_resource  of the parent class.
I have tried using skip_load_and_authorize_resource before it but it skips the loading and authorizing altogether i.e my @user object is nil.
Is there a solution to it?
Parent Class
module Api
  module Cp
    class CpController < Api::ApiController
      load_and_authorize_resource
      
    end
  end
end

Child Class
module Api
  module Cp

    class ParticipantsController < Api::Cp::CpController
      load_and_authorize_resource class: 'User', instance_name: 'user'

      def show
        @user
      end

    end
  end
end


load_and_authorize_resource is actually just a helper method that adds a before_action :load_and_authorize_resource with additional args to the controller.
That means, you can remove the inherited before_action and then add your new version, like this:
module Api
  module Cp
    class ParticipantsController < Api::Cp::CpController
      skip_before_action :load_and_authorize_resource
      load_and_authorize_resource class: 'User', instance_name: 'user'

      # ...

